# Nvidia card not working 100% on Windows XP, need to choose next diagnostic action

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card

I use Windows XP. (Please don't flame me or lecture me about it.)

I used to use a GeForce 9800 GTX, but unfortunately that card died.

I replaced it with a GT 730 and have had two different problems.

Problem #1: The GT 730 does not support suspend on Windows XP. So, basically I have to either keep the computer on or turn it off. Suspend does not work (reliably). It is some hardware problem. It actually does work about 1 in 10 times, but the other 9 times, the computer stays black and I have to reboot which causes chkdsk scans.

Problem #2: Games do not work. The 730 works fine doing normal computing and watching videos. I can watch YouTube no problem, and also Blu-rays and DVDs. Games, however, blue screen the computer. I tried rolling back the driver to 368.69, but that did not do anything. I have not tried a real old rollback like to v280 (my 9800 GTX driver). The bluescreen occurs in nv4_disp.dll at BD03D22A if that means anything. The old 9800 GTX played games no problem before it died.

So, at this juncture I have a couple of different options:

(1) Buy an old graphics card (circa 2014)

(2) Try rolling back my driver to v280

(3) Upgrading to a slightly more advanced modern card like a 740

(4) Try another GT 730 from a different OEM (apparently multiple different manufacturers make the 730)

(5) Try a Gigabyte-branded GT 740 (my motherboard is a Gigabyte)

(6) Try a different line of video card like a GTX 950

(7) enable the "Assign IRQ to VGA" option in my BIOS

Any advice on the best option to try (whether it is above or not)?

Comment: The older graphics card, with an older driver would be the best option. I suspect many games have dropped support for XP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The [Nvidia graphics driver 368.81](https://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/17682/) works fine for my GT730-based card on Windows XP.